# echosign asking for password to enter to view the pdf generated by api /combinedDocument

Tags: javascript, meteor, adobe, acrobat, echosign

Guys i have been working on echosign.I have managed to signed the document from the given api but couldn't view the document.It always ask for password to enter.i have even body content

```
SecurityOption:
      passwordProtection: 'NONE'
      kbaProtection: 'NONE'
      webIdentityProtection: 'NONE'
      protectOpen: false
```

but have no luck with these kind of setting.FYI: i am making post request to https://api.echosign.com/api/rest/v3/agreements/' + argreementId + '/combinedDocument.Guys please help[image]

Comment: Never mind, I was decrypting it wrong